# How to add input and give them an different id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an event click that create an input field each time you click on the link.

```
$("#add_file").click(function(e)
{
        var i = 0;

        $("#input_file").append('<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file"'+i+" />");
        $("#input_file").append('<br />');
        i++;
});
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="add_file">Add file</a>
```

Here no probleme.. In fact I want to add a different Id each time I create my input tag.
Like this :
You click : `<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file1" />`

again : `<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file2" />`

Thx to all :)

EDIT: My  tag doesnt fadeOut like the input what can I do ?

```
var i = 1;

    $("#add_file").click(function(e)
    {
        $("#input_file").append('<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file'+i+'" />');
        $("#input_file").append('<br />');
        $("#input_file").append('<input type="text" name="filename[]" id="file'+i+'" placeholder="Nom du fichier" />');
        $("#input_file").append('<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="removeFile(file'+i+');" id="file'+i+'">x</a>');
        $("#input_file").append('<br />');
        i++;
    });

    function removeFile(name)
    {
        $(name).fadeOut();
    }
```

Comment: If you have a follow-up question, ask it separately.  The argument to `removeFile` should be a string though, and it's not.  And you need to prepend the `#` in the selector somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `i` declaration outside of the function, otherwise it's always redeclared, and always set to `0` and, within the function, increment the variable by `1`:

```
var i = 0;
$('#add_file').click(function(){
    var fileInput = $('<input />', {
        'type' : 'file',
        'id' : 'file' + i,
        'name' : 'file[]'
    }).appendTo('#input_file');
    i++;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9fQLE/1/).

You could, though, avoid using global variables (that are subject to being changed elsewhere within the closure), using an attribute (in this case a given class-name) to keep track of how many elements there are:

```
$('#add_file').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<input />', {
        'type': 'file',
            'id': 'file' + $('.fileInput').length,
            'name': 'file[]',
            'class': 'fileInput'
    }).appendTo('#input_file');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9fQLE/2/).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed and there's no need for self-flagellation; mistakes are the best, if not the *only*, way to learn! ;)

Comment: Thx you for your help !
And yes youre write but when I saw a mistake like that .. I want tio cry :D.
If you can watch my edit I have an other problem .. I try some thing that doesn't really work like i would..

Answer (score 0):

Assign `var i=0` in outside of the function else it always 0

```
var i = 0;
$("#add_file").click(function(e)
{
    $("#input_file").append('<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file"'+i+" /><br />");
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` should be outside click function.

```
var i = 1;
$("#add_file").click(function(e)
{         
    $("#input_file").append('<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file"'+i+" />");
    $("#input_file").append('<br />');
    i++;           
});
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="add_file">Add file</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 1;
$("#add_file").click(function(e){
        $("#input_file").append('<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file"'+i+" />").append('<br />');
        i++;
});
```